# Validate json to ensure all array property value are of same object type

Tags: javascript, json

I need to validate the JSON to ensure that if any property value is of type array, then it must have the same object types.

E.g consider the following example of valid JSON that should be accepted

```
{
    "key1": "val_1",
    "key_2": [{
        "a": "b"
    }, {
        "c": "d"
    }]
}
```

And following is the invalid JSON:

```
{
    "key1": "val_1",
    "key_2": [{
        "a": "b"
    }, {
        "c": "d"
    }, {
        "f": 1
    }]
}
```

Because `{"f": 1}` is different compare to first two nodes. First two nodes have **string** type of value and the **"f"** property value is **numerical**...hence it should be rejected.

I should be able to check and validate any array properties in JSON in this manner.

**What is the best approach to implement this on client side javascript ?**

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that Stack Overflow is a place to get specific answers to problems you encounter while programming, not a code-writing service. Please make an effort to solve the problem yourself, and come back once you have some code and a specific problem. Consider reviewing the helpful article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function to compare an array of objects, returning all which each value is of the selected type

```
function returnTypeMatched(arr,type){
    var r = [];
    if(type === undefined){type = 'String';}
    for(var i=0,ilen=arr.length;i<ilen;i++){
        var o = {},
            item = arr[i],
            keys = Object.keys(item);
        for(var j=0,jlen=keys.length;j<jlen;j++){
            var key = keys[j],
                value = item[key];
            if(arr[i][keys[j]].constructor.name === type){
                o[key] = value;
            }
        }
        if(Object.keys(o).length > 0){r.push(o);}
    }
    return r;
}
```

In your case

```
var myObject = {
        "key1": "val_1",
        "key_2": [{
            "a": "b"
        }, {
            "c": "d"
        }, {
            "f": 1
        }]
    },
    myKeys = Object.keys(myObject);

for(var i=0,ilen=myKeys.length;i<ilen;i++){
    var key = myKeys[i],
        value = myObject[key];
    if(value.constructor.name === 'Array'){
        var firstKeyType = value[0][Object.keys(value[0])[0]].constructor.name;
        myObject[key] = returnTypeMatched(value,firstKeyType);
    }
}

console.log(myObject);
/* Returns
{
    "key1": "val_1",
    "key_2": [{
        "a": "b"
    }, {
        "c": "d"
    }]
}
*/
```